# Union between 2 data set with different schema

Tags: apache-pig

I need one help regarding pig union:

Is it possible that pig can perform union between 2 data set with different schema.

Example:

```
A = LOAD '/user/hdfs/file1' AS (a:int, b:int); 
B = LOAD '/user/hdfs/file2' AS (c:int, d:int, e:chararray, f:float);
UNION ONSCHEMA A, B;
```

Note: The schema of the data set is different.

Comment: Yes, we can union two alias having different schema. Have given an example in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refer : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#union

**inputs :**

**file1 :**

```
1,1
2,2
```

**file2:**

```
1,1,a,1.0
2,2,b,2.0
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'file1'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (a:int, b:int);
B = LOAD 'file2'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (c:int, d:int, e:chararray, f:float);

C = UNION ONSCHEMA A,B;
```

Results :

**DUMP C :**

```
(1,1,,,,)
(2,2,,,,)
(,,1,1,a,1.0)
(,,2,2,b,2.0)
```

**DESCRIBE C :**

```
C: {a: int,b: int,c: int,d: int,e: chararray,f: float}
```